# How can I (safely) convert a dictionary into an UPDATE statement for sqlite in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

Say for example, I have a table of students, and I have a Python dictionary

```
mydict = {"fname" : "samwise", "lname" : "gamgee", "age" : 13}
```

How can I safely generate a Python function that can UPDATE this into my `student` table? (In my use-case I can safely assume that the student already exists in the table, AND I KNOW the `id` already)

I have created a function that achieves this functionality, but I can't help but think it's a bit crude, and perhaps open to SQL injection attacks

```
def sqlite_update(conn, table, data, pkeyname, pkeyval):
    set_lines = ""
    for k,v in data.items():
        set_lines += "{} = '{}', ".format(k,v)

    set_lines = set_lines[:-2] #remove space and comma from last item

    sql = "UPDATE {0} SET {1} WHERE {2} = '{3}'"
    statement = sql.format(table, set_lines, pkeyname, pkeyval)

    conn.execute(statement)
    conn.commit()
```

And to update I just call

```
sqlite_update(conn, "student", mydict, "id", 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I assume you are using `sqlalchemy`. In this case, you can use `sqlalchemy.sql.text` function which escapes strings if required.

You can try to adjust your function as below.

```python
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

def sqlite_update(conn, table, data, pkeyname, pkeyval):
    set_lines = ",".join([f"{k}=:{k}" for k in data.keys()])
    statement = text(f"UPDATE {table} SET {set_lines} WHERE {pkeyname} = :pkeyval")

    args = dict(data)
    args["pkeyval"] = pkeyval
    conn.execute(statement, args)
    conn.commit()
```

For more details, refer to sqlalchemy official documentation on [text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) function.

**EDIT**

As for sqlite3 connection you can do basically the same thing as above, with slight changes.

```python
def sqlite_update(conn, table, data, pkeyname, pkeyval):
    set_lines = ",".join([f"{k}=:{k}" for k in data.keys()])
    statement = f"UPDATE {table} SET {set_lines} WHERE {pkeyname} = :pkeyval"

    args = dict(data)
    args["pkeyval"] = pkeyval
    conn.execute(statement, args)
    conn.commit()
```

Refer to sqlite3 [execute](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)

Comment: I am not using sqlalchemy, what is sqlalchemy?

Comment: _sqlalchemy_ is a database toolkit to communicate with SQL database. What type of variable do you pass under _conn_ variable?

Comment: I am passing a sqlite database connection

Comment: @Fleckenator edited the post for sqlite3 connection

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed widely opened to SQL injection, because you build the query as a string *including its values*, instead of using a parameterized query.

Building a parameterized query with Python is easy:

```
def sqlite_update(conn, table, data, pkeyname, pkeyval):
    query = f"UPDATE {table} SET " + ', '.join(
        "{}=?".format(k) for k in data.keys()) + f" WHERE {pkeyname}=?"
    # uncomment next line for debugging
    # print(query, list(data.values()) + [pkeyval])
    conn.execute(query, list(data.values()) + [pkeyval])
```

With your example, the query displayed by the debug `print` line is:

```
UPDATE student SET fname=?, lname=?, age=? WHERE id=?
```

with the following values list: `['samwise', 'gamgee', 13, 1]`

But beware, to be fully protected from SQL injection, you should sanitize the table and field names to ensure they contain no dangerous characters like `;`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for PostgreSQL, it complains on syntax with the =?

Is there any way to achieve something similar with PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Fleckenator PostgreSQL want `%s` instead of `?` for SQLite. So it would be `UPDATE student SET fname=%s, lname=%s, age=%s WHERE id=%s`